# how to save image from folder to database

Tags: php, mysql, image, save, directory

```
$result=$db->query("SELECT * FROM Table WHERE id='2' ");
while($row = $result->fetch_array())  {
$id=$row["id"]; 
$URL=$row["URL"]; 
}
```

insert img to database MySQL:

```
$files_name = "folder/$URL";

#$files_name = "folder/img.jpg";

$fileSize = filesize($files_name);
$fType = filetype($files_name);
$fileName=$id;

$content = fread($fileSize);
$content = addslashes($content);
fclose($fp);
```

//

```
$Update ="UPDATE Table SET name_file='$fileName',size='$fileSize',type='$fType',content='$content' WHERE id='$id'";
$Up_ok = $db->query ($Update);
```

How to save image from folder to database?

Comment: Last time i worked doing something like that, we stored the image path into DB and images were in a  server folder.

Comment: What doesn't work? What are the errors you get?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest, making a default path, where your system will store all images. Having this path, make a table with each ID designated to an image. In this table just store the image-ID and the ending of each picture path.

So if your picture is stores in path //server/common/images/image1.jpg
You have default path '//server/common/images/' 
and each picture will have sth like 'image1.jpg'